# Why is Steam telling me that I've been "attempting a lot of purchases" and how do I fix it?

Tags: steam

When trying to make a purchase, Steam keeps saying:

> It looks like you've been attempting a lot of purchases in the last few hours. Please wait a while before trying again.

How do I get rid of this message to complete my purchase?

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be a limit in place for how many purchases you can make for a given time.  This kind of feature is usually a safeguard to prevent fraud on someones account.

One [Steam Community post](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/528398719792453543/#c528398719796783552) says that the message went away after about an hour:

> About an hour, but it is super annoying. You could miss some sales if this happens to you at the wrong time!

If your purchase is specifically around the [Steam Deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_Deck) however, it appears Valve is actively trying to prevent scalpers (which have been an issue recently with popular product releases) from grabbing up all the pre-orders for the Steam Deck, as stated in [this article](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/687635-steam-deck-attempting-a-lot-of-purchases-wait-a-while-error-fix).